# Error al Enviar un List en postman

Tags: c#, rest, postman, webapi

Se tiene un web APi rest y un metodo donde debe recibe y devuelve un list; el metodo fue construido asi:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IList<PuertosGP>> ConsultaPuertos(int id, 
   List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP, DateTime fecha)
 {
    PuertosGP puertosGPRepository = new PuertosGP();
    //ConsultaPuertos es una funcion que devuelve un list<>
     var resultList1 = puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(id, lstPuertosGP, 
        fecha);
     return Task.FromResult(resultList1);
   });
```

En mi postman envio los datos asi:

```
[
 {
   "objId":"Frt00002",
   "lstPuertosOne":[
      {
        "ObjID":"Frt00001",
        "Clase":"0.5 S"
     }
  ],
  "lstPuertosTwo":[
     {
        "ObjID":"Frt00002",
        "Clase":"0.2 S"
     }
  ],
  "fecha":"2019-11-14"
 }
]
```

Me esta sacando un Bad Request

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes indicar el la pregunta la clase `PuertosGP`.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta es simple class puertosGP ObjId y clase como atributos

Comment: Y que es `lstPuertosOne` y `lstPuertosTwo` ?, dos elementos del tipo `PuertosGP` de la lista `IList<PuertosGP>`?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta es como envie 2 elementos de la lista. En la imagen puede ser diferente el nombre, pero es simplemente enviar 2 elementos de la lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes **mal construido** el Json, prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
{
   "id": 1, // Es una propiedad del tipo Int
   "lstPuertosGP": 
     [   
        {
          "ObjID":"Frt00001",
          "Clase":"0.5 S"
        },
        {
          "ObjID":"Frt00002",
          "Clase":"0.2 S"
        } 
     ],
   "fecha":"2019-11-14"
}
```

**Nota:** Si el `id` lo estás pasando como parámetro a través de la **Url** (`QueryString`), lo puedes quitar del Json.

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos por el principio, el JSON que estás enviando es erróneo. En el declaras un array de objetos, sin embargo el método no es lo que está esperando.

Si lo que quieres es trabajar con un sólo objeto en el método del controlador, te aconsejaría declarar una clase que tenga el nombre de las propiedades iguales que las del JSON que estas enviando [ clase PuertosGPDto en el código que he añadido debajo ], se podría hacer con nombres diferentes pero habría que utilizar anotaciones que harían el código mas engorroso en este caso.

Con el tema de los métodos del controlador, habría que suplantar ConsultaPuertos por el que necesites de los dos que te proporciono. De esta manera tienes una idea mas clara de como se va a "bindear" las propiedades del JSON que estas enviando a las de la clase que esta definida como parámetro del método en cuestión.

El nombre del parámetro definido en el método, es sólo para poder trabajar con el internamente, no afecta al envío. Además del método y de las clases, añado en los comentarios una prueba de como debería ser la llamada para poder trabajar con ellos.

```
public class PuertosGPDto
{
    public string ObjId { get; set; }
    public List<Lstpuertosone> LstPuertosOne { get; set; }
    public List<Lstpuertostwo> LstPuertosTwo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Metodo para listar la consulta de puertos con una request multiple
/// cuerpo 
/// [
///     {
///        "objId":"Frt00002", 
///        "lstPuertosOne":[{ "ObjID":"Frt00001", "Clase":"0.5 S" }],
///        "lstPuertosTwo":[{ "ObjID":"Frt00002", "Clase":"0.2 S" }],
///        "fecha":"2019-11-14"
///     }
/// ]
/// </summary>
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IList<PuertosGP>> ConsultaPuertosMultiple(List<PuertosGPDto> list)
{
    PuertosGP puertosGPRepository = new PuertosGP();
    //ConsultaPuertos es una funcion que devuelve un list<>
    var listResult = new List<PuertosGP>();
    foreach(var dto in list)
    {
        var consultaPuertosResult = await puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(dto.ObjId, dto.LstPuertosOne, dto.LstPuertosTwo, dto.Fecha);
        listResult.AddRange(consultaPuertosResult);
    }
    return listResult;
}

/// <summary>
/// Metodo para listar la consulta de puertos con una request de un solo elemento
/// cuerpo 
/// {
///     "objId":"Frt00002", 
///     "lstPuertosOne":[{ "ObjID":"Frt00001", "Clase":"0.5 S" }],
///     "lstPuertosTwo":[{ "ObjID":"Frt00002", "Clase":"0.2 S" }],
///     "fecha":"2019-11-14"
/// }
/// </summary>
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IList<PuertosGP>> ConsultaPuertosSingular(PuertosGPDto dto)
{
    PuertosGP puertosGPRepository = new PuertosGP();
    //ConsultaPuertos es una funcion que devuelve un list<>
    var resultList1 = await puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(dto.ObjId, dto.LstPuertosOne, dto.LstPuertosTwo, dto.Fecha);
    return resultList1;
}
```

En los métodos, ya que se están realizando asyncronamente, podemos utilizar la palabra await para esperar la llamada del repositorio sin tener que trabajar con el objeto Task en si mismo.

Así pues, como detalle extra, utilizaría la inyección de dependencias en el constructor del controlador para inicializar el repositorio en ella y así no estar declarando variables en los métodos.

Espero que te ayude ^^